# Buildr: how to make test run before package

Tags: java, automated-tests, integration-testing, war, buildr

I am having a project with **[buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/)** generating war file. For some reason, the 'test' phase is running after the 'war' phase.
But, I need to package some of the test results directly in the war, so my test writes file directly to /src/java/webapp.
However, the 'war' happens before the 'test'.

So, how can I force the 'test' execution happen before the 'war'?

Thanks,
Uri.

Comment: What building system do you use?

Comment: buildr - http://buildr.apache.org/

Comment: Well... found the answer myself... Had to add the exact specific command for test in the execution line, i.e. "clean build MyProject:SubProject:test package"